# displaying a progressbar instead of the refresh menu item in an action bar

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a progress bar instead of a refresh menu item in the action bar. However, when I currently press the refresh button, it disappears, but the progress bar replaces the action bar title, instead of appearing where the refresh button was.

These are my two .xml files:

- The menu item:

  ```
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
      android:visible="true"
      android:orderInCategory="0"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      android:actionLayout="@layout/action_progress_bar"
      android:title="@string/refresh"
      android:titleCondensed="@string/refresh"/>
  ```
- The progress bar layout:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="32dp"
      android:layout_height="32dp" >
  </ProgressBar>
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem is. In order for the progress bar to appear instead of the menu item, it must not have the collapseActionView flag. Removing it, and moving the logic to the code (along with using the easy setActionView method), did the trick

Answer (score 0):

This is a default actionLayout behaviour, and AFAIK you can't change it. Instead you could try something like handling the button click and replacing the bar item from code.

UPDATE:

Take a look at the ActionBarCompat sample project. (New Project/Android Sample Project).

Comment: I tried using setActionView(R.layout.action_progress_bar) when the item is clicked before writing this question. The progress bar was still displayed as a replacement of the title of the action bar, even though the docs of setActionView state that it "will be displayed in place of an automatically generated menu item element"